# Randomly remove one border side from div

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to randomly remove one side, a different side from a couple of divs.
But I can't seem to get it working. Just new to Java, so I don't have much experience.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var exitCards = ['top', 'right', 'bottom', 'left'];
    $('.exit-card').each(function() {
        $(this).css('border-', + exitCards[Math.floor(Math.random() * exitCards.length)], '0 none');
    };
  };
```

Thanks for all the help I can get.

Comment: post your html css code also

Comment: Try removing the comma after `'border-'`.

Comment: working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bRIMOs/bgd5e3z9/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost had it, Just move one `,`

```
$(this).css('border-', +exitCards[Math.floor(Math.random() * exitCards.length)], '0 none');
                     ^
                     Remove this
```

Also you forgot to close your `()`  so `};` should be `});` 
This you forgot 2 times

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var exitCards = ['top', 'right', 'bottom', 'left'];
  $('.exit-card').each(function() {
    $(this).css('border-' +exitCards[Math.floor(Math.random() * exitCards.length)], '0 none');
  });

});
```

```css
.exit-card {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="exit-card"></div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Appreciate the help. Quick response, amazing!

Comment: If this was the solution to the problem, I would recommend that you mark it as the answer to your question, so others with a similar question know what solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

You are missing ')'

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var exitCards = ['top', 'right', 'bottom', 'left'];
    $('.exit-card').each(function() {
        $(this).css('border-' + exitCards[Math.floor(Math.random() * exitCards.length)], '0 none');
    });

  });
```

Check now,
This should work.

Comment: Perfect! Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var exitCards = ['top', 'right', 'bottom', 'left'];
    $('.exit-card').each(function() {
     var item = "border-"+exitCards [Math.floor(Math.random()*exitCards .length)];
        $(this).css({item : '0px'} );
    };

  };
```

Use this ..

Comment: Perfect! Appreciate the help.